# Can't Publish Azure Event Hub Worker Role with EventProcessorHost

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus, azure-eventhub

I can't publish my Event Hub EventProcessorHost worker role. The instance won't start up.. The error I get is:

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException
Stack:
   at ReceiverRole.Receiver.RegisterEventProcessor(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ConsumerGroupDescription, System.String, System.String)
   at ReceiverRole.WorkerRole.Run()
```

This is basically copying Kirk Evans blog example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2015/02/24/scaling-azure-event-hubs-processing-with-worker-roles.aspx

The part that's really getting me is I've done this before. I've used his same example to publish to a different service bus / event hub. So I used that "old" project to post to this new service bus / event hub by redirecting a few urls and everything works fine. When I try to use the new project to post to the new service bus / event hub...no dice. I've stripped this new project down to only the same code he is using...still nada.

I've made sure everything is 4.5.1 (not 4.5.2), the libraries seem the same...I've been looking at this for 2 days and it's driving me nuts!

Update: OK the libraries weren't all the same...and there seems to be a problem. I can get it to work if I back down 
- ServiceBus to 3.0.6 (not 3.0.7)
- Azure Storage Client to 6.0.0 (not 6.1.0)
- EventProcessorHost to 2.0.3 (not 2.0.5)

So somewhere a combination of the latest versions of these libraries is conflicting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue in the 2.0.5 version and the issue was fixed in the new version (2.0.6). We're sorry about the impact. Will you try the new one and let us know if you still see an issue?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.EventProcessorHost

-SJ